# Efcore issue with many 2 many on same entity (Products & RelatedProducts)

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

So i want to add RelatedProducts to my products. So i applied the same relationship type as i did for category. The only difference there is no category class, but we target the same entity. (product). Because the regular many2many works fine, i removed that from my example.

**Goal:**
[image]

Any suggestions?

**Exception:**

```
 "Exception occured: Cannot create a relationship between 'Product.RelatedProducts' and 'RelatedProduct.Related' because a relationship already exists between 'Product.RelatedProducts' and 'RelatedProduct.Product'. Navigation properties can only participate in a single relationship. If you want to override an existing relationship call 'Ignore' on the navigation 'RelatedProduct.Related' first in 'OnModelCreating'."
```

**Product.cs:**

```cs
public class Product : IExportable, IEntityBase
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set;}
    public ICollection<RelatedProduct> RelatedProducts { get; set; }
}
```

**ProductEntityTypeConfiguration.cs**

```cs
internal class ProductEntityTypeConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Product>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Product> builder)
    {
        config.HasKey(p => p.Id);
    }
}
```

**RelatedProducts.cs**

```cs
public class RelatedProduct
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
    
    public int RelatedId { get; set; }
    public virtual Product Related { get; set; }
}
```

**RelatedProductEntityTypeConfiguration.cs**

```cs
public class RelatedProductsEntityConfiguration  : IEntityTypeConfiguration<RelatedProduct>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<RelatedProduct> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(rp => rp.Id);
        builder.ToTable("RelatedProducts");

        builder
            .HasOne(rp => rp.Product)
            .WithMany(p => p.RelatedProducts)
            .HasForeignKey(rp => rp.ProductId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

        builder
            .HasOne(rp => rp.Related)
            .WithMany(p => p.RelatedProducts)
            .HasForeignKey(rp => rp.RelatedId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
    }
}
```

Comment: What you have there is two one-to-many relationships. You don't have any many-to-many relationships. You need a linking-table for many-to-many.

Comment: I've updated the question with a new image. I don't see the difference between the category relation.

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to test this suggestion but I am sure it might work. Why don't you just define your RelatedProduct as:

```
public class RelatedProduct
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    
    public virtual ICollection<Product> Related { get; set; }
}
```

I also suggest you comment out the code in your RelatedProductsEntityConfiguration Configure method

Comment: ? this doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Okay. Let me try one more time. 

````
public class Product : IExportable, IEntityBase
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set;}
    public ICollection<RelatedProduct> RelatedProducts { get; set; }
}
```
```
public class RelatedProduct
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    
    public virtual ICollection<Product> Related { get; set; }
}

```

I am struggling to surround my sample with the code snippet. From your ER diagram I think you are complicating it by how you defined your models